# How to edit JSP and HTML file in Intellij 13.1.6 community

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 13.1.6 Community Edition, but it opens the JSP and HTML file as text file. I installed the plugin named Jsp Internatinalizer, but didn't work.

It works in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition. Is it right not working with the Community Edition?

Comment: you cannot open JSP  in community edition. You need to use ultimate edition

Comment: Also, upgrade to 14.1.3+ already.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just found this. [https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html]. I don't have licenses upgrading to Ultimate Edition. So wanna see if there are some other solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSP and HTML editing/manipulation is only explicitly supported [in the Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: Yes, I just found this. Thanks for your reply. Can Community Edition support this by installing plugins or doing something else?

Comment: @Sky: No, Community Edition wouldn't be able to get past this limitation.  You *might* with a third party plugin (not that I know of any offhand), but it wouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 5):

Later versions of IntelliJ Idea CE provide syntax highlighting for jsps. Checked on `15.0.2`.

Html files has code completion, live templates, emmet abbreviations etc. Even on `12.1.7`

In `File Types` `Settings` you can set to recognize `*.jsp` as html.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on *user2418306* answer,

For MAC,

Preferences (⌘,) -> Editor (left side) -> File Types -> JSP

from the *Registered Patterns* remove *.jsp [image: see image]

now, in HTML, under *Registered Patterns* add *.jsp [image]

[Official Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#change-extension)